# referencing method in backing bean from xtml page

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, autocomplete

When I type on xhtml page samthing like that:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}" validator="#{user.validateName}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="errorName"/>
</h:inputText>
```

For validator attribute when I press ctrl+space eclipse give to me drop down menu with names of backed bean methods. Like that:
user.validateName() with red circle ath satrt of line and user.validateName without bracket starts line with green circle. With frst my validator do not work bath with second it works.
What is manning of this two line, what meaning red circle or green circle, what mean sign like `<class` or `<>something`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Red is `private` member
green is `public`

In case of jsf page editor.

- Green `<` sign means that property is read only propertly, that means no setter method is provided for that property
- Green `<` and Red `>` sign means that property is both read-write.
- Red `>` means property is write only property.
- Green `< class` will return the actuall `Class` of your managedBean.

Suppose you have a class as follows

```
public class LoginBean {

    private String username = "username";
    private String password = "password";

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /*public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }*/


}
```

Then

- `password` will have green `<` because setter method is not there and so it is read only
- `username` will have green`<` and red `>` because it is read/write due to setter getter methods

Comment: Bath next questions is what is with validator="#{user.validateName}

Comment: what do you want to know about validator?

Comment: For validator attribute when I press ctrl+space eclipse give to me drop down menu with names of backed bean methods. Like that: user.validateName() with red circle ath satrt of line and user.validateName without bracket starts line with green circle. With frst my validator do not work bath with second it works

Comment: If it is a red circle, then its private thats why it doesn't work in your xhtml page. For accessing members variables of a managed bean in a jsf page, they need to be public. I hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: No it is same public method with red characters written name of same method end parentheses at the end, and without color written name of same method without parentheses of the end(with this choice everything work fine). For second choice I read that is signature!